# Rails Nested Form Creating Wrong Foreign Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Fairly new to Rails and have tried a number of things here without success.

My problem is when I post to the database with this nested form, one of my tables (apartment_images) posts with the wrong foreign key (apartment_id).

I have a fairly complex model relationship: I have a **Building** has_many_through another table that associates it with (among others) an **Apartments** table. The problematic **apartment_images** table belongs to **Apartments**.

A summarized version is below:

Building Model

```
has_many :building_relationships
has_many :apartments, :through => :building_relationships
accepts_nested_attributes_for :apartments, allow_destroy: true
```

Apartment Model

```
belongs_to :building
has_many :apartment_images, -> { order(position: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy
has_many :building_relationships
has_many :buildings, :through => :building_relationships
```

ApartmentImage Model

```
belongs_to :apartment
```

buildings_controller (excluded new method)

```
def createNewBuilding
    @building = Building.new(building_params)
    @apartment = Apartment.where(building_id: @building.id) 
        #also tried this but results in no id being save:
         #@apartment = @building.apartments.build(apartment_params)

if @building.save
      redirect_to newBuilding_path, notice: "Successfully created building"
    else
      render 'newBuilding'#, notice: "ERROR"
    end


    if apartment_image_params
      apartment_image_params[:image].each do |value|
        @apartment.apartment_images.build({image: value}).save
            end
    end

  end

def apartment_image_params
      #also tried adding :apartment_id. didn't work.
      params.require(:apartment_image).permit(:id, image: []) if params[:apartment_image]
end
```

Comment: I could be misunderstanding, but the foreign key for apartment_image _should_ be apartment_id, since each image belongs to one and only one apartment, and each apartment can have multiple images. Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: basically when i hit submit on the form and check the database it will post the image or images but will associate it with the wrong apartment_id (i.e. not the newly created apartment from the form)

Comment: Why are you using a `has_many though:` relationship between a building and an apartment? surely an apartment can't be in multiple buildings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I finally got it to work. Don't fully understand why this worked vs what I was doing, but will be reading up on it (but I'm also all ears if it's obvious to you guys :) ).

The answer was to switch from using a where / find / findby statement to using Rails magic:

```
def createNewBuilding
@building = Building.new(building_params)
@apartments = @building.apartments
@apartments.each do |apartments|
```